# What should I do with the password?

Tags: homebrew

I tried to install the homebrew and I tried to put my computer password for the 'password' command. But I don't know why I even can't type one word or one number in terminal.

I tried to type my password but it didn't work.

```
Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod u+rwx /usr/local/bin /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib /usr/local/share /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig /usr/local/share/info /usr/local/share/man /usr/local/share/man/man1 /usr/local/share/man/man3 /usr/local/share/man/man5
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
```

Comment: The terminal just doesn't show anything when you type the password, not even stars or dots. That is normal. You probably just typo'd the password or your account doesn't have admin rights.

Comment: How should I fix it? 

Comment: There's nothing to fix because it's not broken. Try again and write the password carefully so that you don't make a typo, or if you don't have a superuser account, ask the IT department or whoever has the superuser account to install the software.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that.